# Unable to return desired value, query and loop keeps returning i

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I was trying to put the results of the query to an array but it's not working intead it only displays i

```
<?php
$sqlo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
$i=1;
while ($h=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlo)) {
    echo "<br>counter[i] : ".$counter[$i] = $h['username'];
    echo "<br>i++ : ".$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: try to add `var_dump($h);` inside `while` loop. What it print?

Comment: suppose to print the username let me try

Comment: I recommend separating the assignment from `echo`, although I think this should work. Also, array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: i'll try it out

Comment: still not working though, still showing letter "i" instead of the usernames

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar suggestion is recommended separating the assignment from echo.

Try this code:

```
<?php
$sqlo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
$i=1;
$counter = [];
while ($h=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlo)) {

    $counter[$i] = $h['username']; //if you need to store username inside an array

    echo "<br>counter[i] : ".$counter[$i];
    echo "<br>i++ : ".$i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

create array variable before loop.

```
$i=1;
$counter[];
while ($h=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlo)) {
    echo "<br>counter[i] : ".$counter[$i] = $h['username'];
    e

echo "<br>i++ : ".$i++;
}
```

Comment: $counter[]; is declared below $i initialization.

Comment: can i use $counter = array(); instead?